# React Devtools - How do i find what proses running between each rendered when using profiler?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-devtools

I'm struggle to track why my `Home page` taking so long to navigating into `Wishlist page`, I'm using `React Devtools` and click record while pressing `Wishlist` Icon, and here's the result

[image]

I don't know how to trace the gap `between` initial render (134.3ms) and 2nd render (843.4ms), why it takes so much time. The result makes my screen stuck at homepage for 843ms and then navigate to `Wishlist` when pressing `Wishlist` Icon.

Any idea how do i track the gap for each `Rendered`?

Answer (score 0):

You're not saying if you're using React of react native but anyway, normally in react dev tools you can use the flame graph to see which component re-renders and how long did it take to render.

Here's the documentation : https://legacy.reactjs.org/blog/2018/09/10/introducing-the-react-profiler.html

See the image below:

[image: flamegraph react]